# Selenium Standalone Exception: Max session count must be greater than 0

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load up a standalone Selenium server on my local machine to test some code. I upgraded Chrome, which means I had to upgrade Chromedriver, which then caused my Unit Test environment to stop working. Therefore, I opted to upgrade Selenium to fix the issue. However, when I run my command:

```
$ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./chromedriver" -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-3.jar standalone
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    08:19:00.496 INFO [EventBusConfig.createBus] - Creating event bus: org.openqa.selenium.events.local.GuavaEventBus
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Max session count must be greater than 0.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.data.NodeStatus.<init>(NodeStatus.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.getStatus(LocalNode.java:239)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.add(LocalDistributor.java:281)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.add(LocalDistributor.java:71)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.commands.Standalone.lambda$configure$1(Standalone.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.launch(Main.java:123)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.main(Main.java:100)
```

I can't seem to find anything out there about this exact error, and everything I find related to problems with sessions is related to the "Grid" concept of hosting a remote Selenium server (which is not what I am trying to do here). I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771379/what-is-wrong-with-my-selenium-grid-configuration) and thought to put the "-browser" argument onto my command above, but apparently standalone mode doesn't even support that as a parameter... or "maxSession".

> Was passed main parameter '-browser' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
>
> Was passed main parameter '-maxSession' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chromedriver binary I put into the directory with the .jar did not have execute permissions.

```
$ chmod +x chromedriver
```

Now everything is working. Isn't it funny how a very fundamental aspect of development is often the problem and the error message seemingly has nothing to do with the actual issue?